Message that says "there is no data" if no records in report
I'm replicating our reports from Qlikview and there are 2 specific ones that sometimes don't have any records for a specific day. With Qlik, there is a message on the distributed report as shown in the pic. Is there a way to generate a similar message in Power BI when there are no records?
I tried using a text box and a card visual to generate the message and it worked BUT it didn't go away when there were records despite layering it behind or in front of the table visuals.sample of message
The main problem is bringing the text box to the front when there's no date and sending it to the back when there is data. Is this even possible with Power BI?
This is the measure dax i tried:
NoClaimsMessage =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Individual' ),
        'Individual'[check_amount] > 10000
    ) = 0
    && CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Group' ),
        'Group'[check_amount] > 10000
    ) = 0,
    "No Claims Over $10K Paid This Report Period",
    ""
)


There is no direct way to achieve this, but here is a workaround.
In this example, there is no data for Widget F and Widget G.

Now, I'll create a measure that applies transparency when the condition is met.
Mask Transparency = IF( SELECTEDVALUE( 'Product Dim'[Product] ) in {"Widget F", "Widget G"}, "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF00" )

Then, I'll create a Shape instead of a Card.

Next, I'll go to Shape > Style > Fill and click on the fx option.

Then, I'll select Field Value for Format Style and use the previously created measure.

Finally, I'll navigate to Shape > Style > Text and click on fx.

Here, I'll use a measure to display a message when the conditions are met, similar to yours.

Position the Shape over the table, and that should do it.
Here is the final result.



In your Mask Transparency measure I see Widget F & Widget G being hardcoded, Is there a way this can be made dynamic please? Thank you - @agustin palacios

My example is not a logical condition based on mathematics, so it has to be hardcoded. You can modify the measure to meet your requirements, and it will still work
